# How to get end of play event in VlcControl with Winforms?

Tags: c#

I need to handle the end of stream playback event, but exclude manually stopping the stream playback.

There is a "Stopped" event and you can use it. But how can I determine if the stop was done by the user or at the end of playback?

Other than adding a flag field like "isManualStop", nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Maybe you need `EndReached` event.

Comment: @i486. Thank you, you're right. Although I've tried this event before, but decided for some reason that it was related to the end of stream buffering. Unfortunately the wiki doesn't even have a brief description of the most necessary events, but I found a discussion of a part of the code on the internet and there is just this event.